# Logging inside Framework?

Tags: android, logging

I am trying to develop small application for reset Logging on Phone.
Can some one throw some Lights on how to achieve logging in AndriodRunTimeInit whenever there is exception? I want to write into file whenever there is RunTime exception.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended that you use Android's built in logging via [`Log`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html). You can access the log via `adb logcat` and don't have to worry about anything else.